# Where to find official publication ethics guidelines and best practices?

Tags: publications, ethics, reference-request, self-plagiarism

I am quite confused by publication ethics issues in academics, related to:

- **redundancy of data** using the same data set in different publications
- **redundancy of description** using the same figures or part of text to describe instruments, data set or samples
- **redundancy of results** using results in more than one publications for highlighting different aspect of the results

I have tried to find some guidelines, I found [Int J Clin Pract Suppl. 2007 Jan; 61 (Suppl 152): 1–26.](//dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1742-1241.2006.01230.x), but I was wondering if there was a white paper or something more official.

I would, however, appreciate any guidelines or advice to solve these doubts.

Comment: Check out your professional societies and their webpage. For example, the American Statistical Association has published professional [ethics](http://www.amstat.org/ASA/Your-Career/Ethical-Guidelines-for-Statistical-Practice.aspx) and also [here](http://www.amstat.org/asa/files/pdfs/EthicalGuidelines.pdf). The second link does address some aspects of publication, but not necessarily the answers you are looking for. Hence a comment rather than an answer from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to follow the COPE (Committee on Publication Ethics) guidelines to get enough idea on your mentioned issues. You could also find the some exemplary cases ([here](https://publicationethics.org/cases)) and how are then being handled by journals or the COPE boards.

Briefly, it says:

"*COPE is a forum for editors and publishers of peer reviewed journals to discuss all aspects of publication ethics. It also advises editors on how to handle cases of research and publication misconduct.*" (Source: [COPE Homepage](https://publicationethics.org/))

Further, you could also find publisher-wise publication ethics guidelines, though they follow more or less the same practice:

1. [Elsevier Publishing Ethics Resource](https://www.elsevier.com/editors/perk)
2. [Springer Publication Ethics for Journals](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/editors/publishing-ethics-for-journals/4176)
3. [IEEE Publication Ethics](https://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_ethics.html)
4. [Wiley Publication Ethics Guidelines for Authors](https://authorservices.wiley.com/editors/ethical-guidelines/index.html)
5. [ACS Code of Ethics](https://www.acs.org.au/content/dam/acs/rules.../Code-of-Professional-Conduct_v2.1.pdf)

A brief browsing through the above would give you a lot of information on such stuff, which one must know before entering into the research world.